# How can I use the same material at another slot and change it independently?

Tags: materials

I modelled something and want to select some specific faces for this object to give it another material. Works with applying. But now I have an existing material and don't know how to change it (e.g. make it darker) without changing it for all the other faces too.

[image]

When I click on the second material slot and want to change it and apply, the first slot changes too. How do I avoid that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click the *New Material* button - to add a new material based on your current one.
Then change the new material.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped!

Comment: Great, good luck with your project :)

Comment: Great as always :) Does it differ from pressing the number (to make it single user)?

Comment: @vklidu I believe you get the same result :). I use it because the button is always there.